Can't use the Airflow module and show the TypeError 'module' object is not callable
I am using WSL2 ubuntu linux system and try to use Airflow on Windows
Operating on Vscode
I installed the 2.4.1 version of Airflow
When I tried to ,
I got the below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/stevenluk18/airflow/airflow_env/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    
from airflow.__main__ import main
  
File "/home/stevenluk18/airflow/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    
from airflow import settings
  
File "/home/stevenluk18/airflow/airflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 49, in <module>
    
TIMEZONE = pendulum.tz.timezone('UTC')

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


What's the problem? Please help!!!

When I try to , I got the TypeError. And I have try create the Linux Venv and activate with venv/bin/activate. I pip install the apache-airflow, still I can't call the package function. I used the <export AIRFLOW_HOME=pwd> command to locate the file that I'm working on and still not work.
And when I install the Airflow packages: python-nvd3, unicodecsv, google-re2.
Can't build wheel for these packages inside apache-airflow.
Will it affect the outcome?
